# Can I save output from a previous terminal command using only the keyboard?

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I just spent the last two hours running a `dd` command *(or picture any similar "difficult to re-do" scenario)* from a live CD without a GUI; all I have is my trusty "multi-window" (`CTRL+ALT+F#`) Bash terminal.

Alas, during the command `dd` threw out several nasty error messages and a bit more information that I would like to keep. I have a USB drive plugged in to which I can write data, but how do I get the previous output saved as a text file after the command has already been run?

If this had been a terminal emulator inside a nice GUI, I would have simply used my mouse to select the text, copy it, and paste it into a document. And had I known the command would have produced errors, I would have piped it out to a file to begin with, but alas, the additional output came as a surprise.

**How do I save text output from my previous command to a file without re-running the command?** Is this even possible?

Comment: I have been searching for ways to select text on the screen, but so far I'm only finding ways of doing this using text you have entered into the prompt.

Comment: Have you tried using output redirection??

Comment: @eyoung100 Is that another word for "piping"? As in `dd if=/dev/sda of=/backups/sda.img > result.txt`. If so, the problem is _I already ran the `dd` command_. At all costs, I want to avoid running the command again, which in some situations is impossible.

Comment: @eyoung100 - not possible - the data is already written to the terminal. IQAndreas - are the `/dev/vcsa*[1-9]*` devices populated for you?

Comment: A pipe behaves differently than an output operator.  A pipe takes output from one command and "feeds it into" the next command.   An output operator outputs command output to a file if needed.  @mikeserv is correct though, you can't interactively log data after the operation.

Comment: Assuming this is Linux: install [gpm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/gpm). (Start it if necessary, e.g. `service start gpm`). Sweep out a region while holding down the left mouse button. Type `cat > outputfile` and click on the right mouse button to paste the region you just selected.

Comment: If the objective is solely "to keep ... [the] information", a last resort is to grab a camera and take a photograph of the screen. (And, theoretically, you could then run OCR on that.)

Comment: If you use `screen` or `tmux`, you can select regions of the screen (and scroll back too) and copy/paste, using only the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest `screen`, too, but that only helps if you were expecting to need it.  (also, from what I hear, `tmux` is better.  I still use screen because I already know it.)

Answer (score 15):

A linux kernel should store an on-screen log for your vts in the corresponding `/dev/vcsa*[ttynum]` device.

It is why the following works:

```
echo hey >/dev/tty2
dd bs=10 count=1 </dev/vcs2
```

...which prints...

```
hey
```

The corresponding `/dev/vcsa[ttynum]` device will store an encoded version of the formatted text on-screen, whereas the `/dev/vcs[ttynum]` will be a plain dump. The `vcsa[ttynum]` devices will encode a pair of bytes which describe each on-screen char and its attributes, as well as a string at the head of each logical page that indicates the referenced tty's *lines,columns* count.

As @kasperd points out, I had it wrong before by assuming the `\a` BEL was encoded between every character, when in fact: *The default color combination happens to coincide with the bell character.*

For your purposes using the `/dev/vcs[ttynum]` is probably easiest. Here's a `l`ook at the differences:

```
echo hey >/dev/tty2
dd bs=10 count=1 </dev/vcs2 |
sed -n l
```

...prints...

```
hey       $
```

...and...

```
echo hey >/dev/tty2
dd bs=10 count=1 </dev/vcsa2 |
sed -n l
```

...prints...

```
0\200\000\004h\ae\ay\a$
```

Comment: `vcsa` doesn't put the same character between all characters. It give you pairs of bytes telling you which character is on the screen and which color it has. The default color combination happen to coincide with the bell character.

Comment: @kasperd - thank you. Is it better?

Comment: That's better. 

Answer (score 3):

Go to (/log in on) another terminal and run `sudo screendump N > screenoutput.txt`, where `N` is the number of the terminal you want.

No backlog, I fear.  If those virtual consoles keep one, I've never seen it.  But it gets you all you can see on that terminal.

Comment: if it does work, it's probably because it grabs it from `/dev/vcsa*[1-9]*` - *(which is what I would guess the superuser permissions are for)*. The linux consoles have supported a backlog for most of the 3.* series as well, I think. I'm not sure how one might grab it *(opposed to using the `/dev/vcsa*[1-9]*` devices)* but maybe there's a way.

Comment: It's better not to switch to a different console, as switching erases the backlog, retaining only what is currently visible on the screen.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes.  Well, the man page seems to say it uses _both_ `/dev/vcs$i` and `/dev/vcsa$i`.  It gives a readable result though. ;-)

Comment: @Gilles Ah, so there is a backlog? But `screendump` doesn't get at it, even if I stay in the same console.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it seems you don't get the backlog in `/dev/vcs` (and hence not from `screendump` either). I don't know how to get at it then.

Comment: You can see the scrollback by typing Shift-PageUp one or more times. I don't know of a way to snarf the text in the scrollback other than using the mouse via gpm.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So I see. But to grab more than a single page via gpm sounds tricky. I guess you could do as Scott suggests (and as a friend of mine once did with a BSOD): Grab a camera.

Comment: @mikeserv most of the 3.x series?  I think I remember using shift-pageup on a Linux text console as far back as 2.4.  But definitely early 2.6.  I *think* I remember increasing the size of the buffer before compiling my kernel, back in the day when just running X used a decent % of your total RAM.  The catch is that the scroll buffer is discarded when switching VTs.  Linux only allocates memory for a screen of text per VT + the one shared scrollback buffer.

Comment: @TheSidhekin Yep, photographs of screens are a time-honoured way of capturing hard lockups, boot problems, or display corruption for bug reports.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I was hedging - but was it always default? I seem to remember reading something about vts and scrollback and 3.0 recently. Could be I imagined it.

Comment: Maybe something changed, but I know I've been using shift+pgup since before 3.0.  And since before this trend of having annoying mode-switching during bootup that kills the scrollback to see weird stuff that got printed during bootup.  Real men (and real women) picked a good VGA text mode that looked good on their video card / monitor, and put it in `lilo.conf` on the kernel command line.

Comment: And don't get me started on framebuffer console crap.  When your video hardware accelerates fullscreen text to be blazing fast, doing it with software just to get a different font is nonsense when it cuts performance of `ls`ing a big directory or `cat`ting a big file by 2 orders of magnitude or so.  (yeah yeah, languages support for non-ASCII-using languages, but I was still annoyed when it was enabled by default while it was still dog-slow.)